# Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream in web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream. MIME multipart message is not complete error comming when override `Stream::GetStream` method of `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider`. I am getting stream in `GetStream` method and encrypt it and returning it than it gives me this error (Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream). I have done all previous solutions, but doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```
var Savedfiledata = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).ContinueWith(

                (Task<CustomMultipartFormData> readTask) =>
                {
                    CustomMultipartFormData CMF = readTask.Result;// Here Error is comming

                    // Create response containing information about the stored files.

                    return CMF.FileData.Select(fileData =>
                    {
                        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(fileData.LocalFileName);
                        ContentDispositionHeaderValue disposition = fileData.Headers.ContentDisposition;

                        string filename = (disposition != null && disposition.FileName != null) ? disposition.FileName : string.Empty;

                        CS_FileUpload FileObj = new CS_FileUpload()
                        {
                            FileName = filename.Replace("\"", ""),
                            FileUniqueName = info.Name,
                            FileSize = (info.Length / 1024),
                            FilePath = info.DirectoryName,
                            FileType = info.Extension,
                            InsertDate = info.LastWriteTimeUtc,
                        };

                        DAObj.CS_FileUpload.Add(FileObj);
                        return FileObj;

                    }).ToList();

                });
```

public override Stream GetStream(HttpContent filedata, HttpContentHeaders headers)
        {

```
        Stream reqStream = filedata.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            reqStream.CopyTo(stream);
            MemoryStream getEncBytes = Encrypt(stream, GenerateKey());
            return getEncBytes;
        }

    }
```